# FormData in IE10 not working

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, internet-explorer-10

I know many have asked this question, but again here it is. FormData in IE10 is not working.
Can i know the reason and if not possible then any alternative. I have gone through below link which says its possible.

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Any relevant answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by including meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" >
```

Comment: Thanks you! You save my day!